# Can notepad++ regex find a string and replace with a new string that contains the found string

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have the following text:

```
.clk,
.rst_b,
.phase_in
```

I want the follwing:

```
.clk(clk),
.rst_b(rst_b),
.phase_in(phase_in)
```

That is-

1. find a string starting with a period and excluding a trailing comma that may or may not be present.
2. Append the string, excluding the period to the found string inside parenthesizes.

Notepad++ has the function "find and replace" not "find and append" therefore step two could be written as follows - replace the string with a copy of itself followed by a copy of itself enclosed in parenthesizes.

Step one is completed by `\.\w+`. Any thoughts on step 2?

Thanks!

Comment: Typically, the variables `\1,\2,...` capture the values of any capture groups in the regexp, i.e., `/\.(\w+)/.\1\1/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple regex like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can! Use capture groups to refer to the matched word in your replacement.

Replace `\.(\w+)` with `.\1\(\1\)`.

The parentheses mean that we want to keep a reference to `\w+`. We access that reference with `\1` in the replacement.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regular expression. This captures word characters following the dot.

```
Find: ^\.(\w+)
Replace: .\1\(\1\)
```

**Explanation**:

```
^          # the beginning of the string
\.         # '.'
(          # group and capture to \1:
  \w+      #   word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or more times)
)          # end of \1
```

In the replacement, we use `\1` to reference what was matched and captured by capturing group `#1`. **Note**: You need to escape the parentheses in the replacement to actually display them.

Answer (score 1):

use `\1` find `\.(\w+)` and replace with `\.\1\(\1\)`

Answer (score 0):

Find what: `\.([^,]+)`

Replacement: `.$1\($1\)`

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/sE4jY1/2)

Make sure regex expression radio button is checked and dot matches newline is unchecked.

Pattern explanation:

```
  \.                       '.'
  (                        group and capture to \1:
    [^,]+                    any character except: ',' (1 or more times)
  )                        end of \1
```